# Turn off AUCTeX's changing double quotes to single quotes

Tags: auctex

I use Emacs, with AUCTeX.  When I type a double quote character " AUCTeX changes it to a pair of single quotes, either `` or ''.  I often need double quotes in this document; how can I turn that behavior off?  (I've peered at  customize-group  AUCTeX  but none of the options seemed right.)

Comment: Pressing `"` twice gives a literal `"`.

Comment: Fair enough, but is there a way to stop it doing that in the first place?

Comment: I think you can toggle the user option `TeX-quote-after-quote` so the feature `egreg` describes is reversed.

Comment: @JimHefferon Did you customize `TeX-quote-language-alist`?

Comment: TeX-quote-after-quote seems to work.  Thank you!

Comment: Do you use Unicode for your documents? Then the ASCII 022 Quotation Mark " is just one of many options you have. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Electronic_documents). Then how to enter Unicode characters with Emacs is worth a look. Regardless of the encoding the packages [`csquotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) might also be worth a look.

Comment: `M-x set-variable RET TeX-quote-after-quote RET 0 RET` seems does what is required (it can be any value that isn't `nil`) `M-x set-variable RET TeX-quote-after-quote RET nil RET` should return things to normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Mark Wibrow.  Toggling the user option `TeX-quote-after-quote` does what I need.