# Unexpected behaviour when typing quotes with babel

Tags: babel, emacs, auctex

Using AUCTeX, with `\documentclass[italian]{article}` and `babel`, when I type quotes i get `"<` or `">`:

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
"<bla">
\end{document}
```

It doesn't happen if I don't use `babel`:

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\begin{document}
``bla''
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, better use the `csquotes` package

Comment: Related: [Turn off AUCTeX's changing double quotes to single quotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220936) and [How can I avoid AUCTeX wrongly inferring the language of a document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192172)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You're right about `csquotes` and I usually use it. This time I was in a hurry, I'd loaded just a couple of packages and I didn't expect AUCTeX to do some magic even without it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior is actually expected and documented in [AUCTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Style-Files-for-Different-Languages):

> #### 5.4.1.2 Style Files for Different Languages
>
> AUCTeX supports style files for several languages. Each style file may
>   modify AUCTeX to better support the language, and will run a language
>   specific hook that will allow you to for example change ispell
>   dictionary, or run code to change the keyboard remapping.
>
> ‘italian’
>   Runs style hook TeX-language-it-hook. Pressing `"` will
>   insert `"<` and `">` depending on context.

If you're not satisfied with this behavior, customize [`TeX-quote-language-alist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dquote_002dlanguage_002dalist) with <kbd>M-x customize-variable RET TeX-quote-language-alist RET</kbd>:

> User Option: **`TeX-quote-language-alist`**
>
> Used for overriding the default
>   language-specific quote insertion behavior. This is an alist where
>   each element is a list consisting of four items. The first item is the
>   name of the language in concern as a string. See the list of supported
>   languages above. The second item is the opening quotation mark. The
>   third item is the closing quotation mark. Opening and closing
>   quotation marks can be specified directly as strings or as functions
>   returning a string. The fourth item is a boolean controlling quote
>   insertion. It should be non-nil if if the special quotes should only
>   be used after inserting a literal `"` character first, i.e. on second
>   key press.

Using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, as suggested by @ChristianHupfer, is also recommended.